# strcat appending multiple times when called in loop

Tags: esp8266, c

The strcat function is working fine when called for the first time but when the broker goes down and it's attempting to reconnect it is appending the value twice. I am not able to figure out the problem as i am writing C code for the first time.

```
void reconnect() {

  while (!client.connected()) {
    const char* cid = clientID.c_str();
    if (client.connect(cid)) {
       const char* sTopic = strcat("clm/",cid);
       client.publish(outTopic, sTopic);
       client.subscribe(sTopic);
    } else {
    // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
    for(int i = 0; i<5000; i++){
      delay(1);
    }
  }
}
```

}

It is called in the loop method

```
void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
}
```

The value of sTopic for the first time is `clm/5C:CF:7F:3D:5B:F6` but when the broker restarts and the client connects again it is `clm/5C:CF:7F:3D:5B:F65C:CF:7F:3D:5B:F6`

What could be the reason for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strcat won't allocate any memory for the new string. So what really happens is that the location where the string constant `"clm/"` is stored gets the id appended.

In other words the second time around it's as if you passed `"clm/5C:CF:7F:3D:5B:F6"` as first parameter.

To fix that you need to supply a proper buffer for strcat to do its work:

```
if (client.connect(cid)) {
   char[64] sTopic ={0};
   strcat(sTopic , "clm/");
   strcat(sTopic , cid);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Appends a copy of the *source* string to the *destination* string.

[source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

Congratulations, you've broken your string literal. Either stick to using `String` or make sure you allocate a string properly and then concatenate into that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cat only one string per time. Your assumption is that it performs

```
dest = strcat(string_1, string_2)
```

However, it is:

```
dest = strcat(dest, string_1)
```

So you should use

```
char sTopic[256]; // Max possible length

...

strcpy(dest, "clm/");
strcat(dest, cid);
```

This will first copy "clm/" to dest, than cid will be concatenated.

(code not tested)

See reference: [reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm)